# Android 5.0 Lollipop and 4.4 KitKat ignores my WiFi network, enableNetwork() is useless

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-5.0-lollipop, connectivity

My app **connect directly to a hardware device** that act as an access point (with no access to internet).

I can't connect because Android 5.0 automaticcaly switch to a valid internet connection, so if I have data connection (3G, 4G, ...) or a pre-configured network I can't connect to my device because it ignores the WiFi.

So how can I force Android to use the network I activated programatically?

I'm simply using:

```
wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true))
```

where `id` is the network of my device I want to connect to. The `true` parameter is useless.

The suggested solution that use `ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork()` has no effect.

Comment: I strongly suggest you file a bug on b.android.com to get the official take on this. IMO as per the documentation of `wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true)`, thinks should continue working as they were before. If they don't then it is a bug. Also, what devices have you tried?

Comment: @curioustechizen I'm on a nexus 5 with lollipop

Comment: @curioustechizen As you say, enableNetwork() should continue working, I found a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a workaround to enable the desidered network on Lollipop:

[WifiConfiguration enable network in Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986023/wificonfiguration-enable-network-in-lollipop)

Now this is my code after calling `wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true)`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    List<WifiConfiguration> networks = wm.getConfiguredNetworks();
    Iterator<WifiConfiguration> iterator = networks.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = iterator.next();
        if (wifiConfig.SSID.replace("\"", "").equals(wc.SSID.replace("\"", "")))
            wm.enableNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId, true);
        else
            wm.disableNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId);
    }
    wm.reconnect();
}
```

maybe the secret is the call to `reconnect()`, I don't know at this time.

**UPDATE**
Unfortunately, this workaround only works if a valid WiFi connection is active before executing the code. Does not works if you're connect by 3G only.

**UPDATE 19 Jan 2015**

This code actually works for me on Android 5/6.0.x:

```
//bind to current thread
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    connManager.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So it measns that currently there is no way to connect to a specific WiFi network on KitKat?

Comment: @Seraphim's Is there anyway to connect on KitKat?

Comment: @SamvelKartashyan Still not working for me on 4.4. Seems to be very tricky to solve or, maybe, I'm very stupid. Let me know If you succeeded.

Comment: @Seraphim's solved that issue. Please check my answer. it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can try to use new Lollipop API [ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestNetwork%28android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback%29), supposedly like this:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
cm.requestNetwork(new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                  .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                  .setNetworkSpecifier("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX")
                  .build(),
                  new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                      void onAvailable(Network network) {

                      }
                  });
```

where `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` is your WiFi SSID. I'm not sure about it's format, and if it's used at all, I did not find any references to `setNetworkSpecifier` inside Android sources, except for the `NetworkCapabilities` class.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to correctly format the SSID. Here is a sample code:

```
    WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration tmpConfig = new WifiConfiguration();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        tmpConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", sSSID);
        tmpConfig.BSSID = sBSSID;
    } else {
        tmpConfig.SSID = "\"" + sSSID + "\"";
        tmpConfig.BSSID = "\"" + sBSSID + "\"";
    }

    tmpConfig.priority = 1;
    if (iSecurityType.equals("WEP")) {
        tmpConfig.wepKeys[0] = sPassword;
        tmpConfig.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    } else if (iSecurityType.equals("WPA2") ||   iSecurityType.equals("WPA")) {
            tmpConfig.preSharedKey = "\"" + sPassword+ "\"";
        } else {
            tmpConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        }

    tmpConfig.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    int netId = mWifiManager.addNetwork(tmpConfig);

    mWifiManager.updateNetwork(tmpConfig);
    boolean result = mWifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    mWifiManager.updateNetwork(tmpConfig);
    mWifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```