# WifiConfiguration enable network in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-5.0-lollipop

I was working on Wifi project, there is a module that enable user to join wifi programatically.

In kitkat and below it's working successfully, but in Lollipop it's not working.

Here is the code :

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"testSSID\"";
wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = true;
wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement
.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + netId);
boolean checkEnableWifi = wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + checkEnableWifi);
```

my tested device is nexus 5 build number LRX21O, is ther something wrong in my code or bug on Lollipop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Faced similar issue on lollipop.

Disabling other networks manually, an then reconnecting wifi manager solved the issue.

```
boolean enableNework(String ssid, Context cxt) {
    boolean state = false;
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) cxt.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wm.setWifiEnabled(true)) {
        List<WifiConfiguration> networks = wm.getConfiguredNetworks();
        Iterator<WifiConfiguration> iterator = networks.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = iterator.next();
            if (wifiConfig.SSID.equals(ssid))
                state = wm.enableNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId, true);
            else
                wm.disableNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId);
        }
        wm.reconnect();
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: Had similar issue, thanks! This is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982778/android-5-0-lollipop-and-4-4-kitkat-ignores-my-wifi-network-how-can-i-avoid-the/27570523#27570523

Comment: It kinda works for me. Tnx.  On a Nexus 7, the connection shows up with "Authentication Problem".  Going in and touching "Connect" completes the connection.  Some kind of timing issue?

Comment: Also, this did not seem to work on a Android ICS 4.0.4.  The old way works fine there.  What a pain...

Comment: @SoloPilot Did you manage to get it working? My problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712432/connecting-to-wifi-network-automatically-in-android-5-and-6

Answer (score 6):

Try this. Do not disable other saved networks. As it will hinder the fallback of wifi on other networks when your selected network is not available. Play with the priority.

```
/*
 *  Max priority of network to be associated.
 */
private static final int MAX_PRIORITY = 999999;

/**
 * Allow a previously configured network to be associated with.
 */
public boolean enableNetwork(String ssid) {
    boolean state = false;
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    if(list != null && list.size() > 0) {
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(convertToQuotedString(ssid))) {

                wifiManager.disconnect();

                int newPri = getMaxPriority() + 1;
                if(newPri >= MAX_PRIORITY) {
                    // We have reached a rare situation.
                    newPri = shiftPriorityAndSave();
                }

                i.priority = newPri;
                wifiManager.updateNetwork(i);
                wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

                state = wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return state;
}

private int getMaxPriority() {
    final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    int pri = 0;
    for (final WifiConfiguration config : configurations) {
        if (config.priority > pri) {
            pri = config.priority;
        }
    }
    return pri;
}

private void sortByPriority(final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations) {
    Collections.sort(configurations,
        new Comparator<WifiConfiguration>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(WifiConfiguration object1, WifiConfiguration object2) {
                return object1.priority - object2.priority;
            }
        });
}

private int shiftPriorityAndSave() {
    final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    sortByPriority(configurations);
    final int size = configurations.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        final WifiConfiguration config = configurations.get(i);
        config.priority = i;
        wifiManager.updateNetwork(config);
    }
    wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    return size;
}

/**
 * Add quotes to string if not already present.
 *
 * @param string
 * @return
 */
public static String convertToQuotedString(String string) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(string)) {
        return "";
    }

    final int lastPos = string.length() - 1;
    if (lastPos > 0
            && (string.charAt(0) == '"' && string.charAt(lastPos) == '"')) {
        return string;
    }

    return "\"" + string + "\"";
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine (although I noticed lots of differences in connecting speed between various devices). Thanks, disabling other networks is unacceptable, I think.

Comment: Disabling networks was insufficient on my device. This seems to work instead.

Comment: Can you change the priority for Android 6+ ?

Comment: tested on 6+, it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); at the end of your code.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It marked as saved in Wi-Fi setting

Answer (score 0):

try setting false where you are trying to diable other networks.

```
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, false);
```

and one more thing if your addNetwork succeeds then you can proceed with the rest. if it returns a -1 you cannot call enableNetwork as the netId you are using would be -1. so what you could ideally do is

```
netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
if(netId >= 0){
Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + netId);
boolean checkEnableWifi = wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + checkEnableWifi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a situation on Nexus 7 connecting to hp printer in which the method `enablenetwork(id,true)` return true but still does not connect. Answer from  @Santosh and @Seraphim helped me..Disabling each network and enabling only the required SSID worked.